# understanding Green's theorem Intuition

Tags: integration, intuition, vector-analysis

The idea of it is to find the area of a region, yet I keep seeing vector fields popping up all over the place.

Take this example from my text book: Find the region enclosed by the two graphs:

$y = x$, $y = x^2$

I have no idea how they put this thing in the form of:
$$\int_{c} y^3dx + (x^3 + 3xy^2)dy$$

Where did that come from? And this isn't the only problem where vector fields are appearing out of nowhere and not being described how they came about. Can someone help me out here?

EDIT: I'm talking about where the $y^3$ and $(x^3 + 3xy^2)$ came from

Comment: Yes. Apologies.

Comment: The area enclosed by the two graphs is $A=\int_{0}^{1}(x-x^2)dx=\frac16$. And if I did the line integral correctly, it's value is $\int_{c} y^3dx + (x^3 + 3xy^2)dy=\frac{3}{20}$, which implies you *can't* put it in that form. Either you didn't transcribe the problem from your textbook correctly, or your textbook is wrong.

Comment: I transcribed it correctly. Now I am reeeeally confused. I guess the point of my question is to say how is it that those numbers $y^3$ and $(x^3 + 3xy^2)$ are being created? What's the method?